# Has anyone reverse engineered and published common in-camera adjustments by major manufacturers?

Tags: algorithms

Most cameras offer various in-camera adjustments to produce jpeg output. For example, Olympus has an adjustment to adjust saturation:

[image]

In theory, one could compare the raw file with the resultant changes to the jpeg and reverse engineer the algorithm being used to generate this adjustment. Has anyone done this for common camera adjustments? I realize there are "standard" algorithms to do these things, but each manufacturer implements their version of the algorithm differently.

(Note: I am not talking about complicated "artistic filters", but standard adjustments, saturation, brightness, contrast, sharpness, WB, etc.)

Comment: "... compare the raw file..." in what way? To view the 'raw' file it has to be demosaiced using one algorithm or another. Different applications used to view raw files will display the same file differently. Even the same application will vary the way it displays the same raw file based on the selected default settings. You could only compare jpegs shot at different settings (or demosaiced after the fact at different settings).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there a number of such efforts. See this [Darktable blog post](http://www.darktable.org/2016/05/colour-manipulation-with-the-colour-checker-lut-module/) for an overview of some of them. This refers to [Pascal's ColorMatch](https://github.com/pmjdebruijn/colormatch), a script with creates ICC profiles based on out-of-camera JPEGs shot against a known color target.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the work of Guillermo Luijk.
(Use google translate)

[Reverse engineering of RGB curves with R](http://www.elmomentodecisivo.com/2017/09/ingenieria-inversa-de-curvas-rgb-con-r.html)